# How to filter in PUB/SUB ( ZeroMQ ) with protobuf binaries?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, zeromq

I use Go, ZeroMQ, and protobuf to write a microservice.

ZeroMQ with a `PUB/SUB` archetype. (`zmq4` lib in Go). How to use a filter in a `SUB` message with binary protobuf message?

For example my proto message:

syntax = "proto3";

```
message UserMessage {
    string userId = 1;
    string msg    = 2;
}
```

I would like to filter the messages for a `SUB` client with a value of `userId`:

```
listener.SetSubscribe("42") // <-string not working.
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it:

```
listener.SetSubscribe( string( []byte{ 10, 2 } ) + "42" )
```

Comment: You might have already observed, that unless the Go-binding does some behind the scene magics, the native ZeroMQ API is doing a purely binary match on the left side of the message payload, against the set TOPIC-string. This need not, but may, collide with some ( protobuf or other protocol-related ) compositions that a message payloads are subject to, so do not forget, that the underlying API does nothing more than just a left-aligned string-(byte)-matching against any present item, stored in the actual state of the list of set TOPIC-strings. Anyway,enjoy the powers of the Zen-of-Zero in ZeroMQ

Comment: @user3666197 Thank you for comment